# ColorFunction with InterpolationFunction in RegionPlot3D

Tags: colors, wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

I am writing to ask a question regarding the implementation of a field-dependent color in a 3d region plot in Mathematica.

Specifically, I have created the following plot, where f[x,y,z] is an interpolating function of a three-dimensional array (this is done to have lower resolution plots with ease, since the amount of data in the array is significant).

The problem I am encountering is that if I run the following instruction:

```
RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] >= 0.5 && f[x, y, z] <= 0.6, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,0.416}, {z, 0, 0.666}, 
 ColorFunction ->  Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[Rescale[f[x, y, z], {0, 1}]]]]
```

The color is not imposed correctly (i get a region of uniform color). If I utilize a function g instead (can be any function, e.g. the norm of the point position) inside the Hue, so that

```
Hue[Rescale[g[x, y, z], {0, 1}]]
```

the color information is passed correctly. I assume that I am making a mistake with the handling of InterpolatingFunction objects. How should this problem be handled?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegionPlot3D` passes 4 arguments to `ColorFunction` :

Try this (just adding a dummy arg to `Function` )

```
 RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] >= 0.5 && f[x, y, z] <= 0.6, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,0.416}, {z, 0, 0.666}, 
      ColorFunction ->  Function[{x, y, z, p}, Hue[Rescale[f[x, y, z], {0, 1}]]]]
```

or like this:

```
 RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] >= 0.5 && f[x, y, z] <= 0.6, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,0.416}, {z, 0, 0.666}, 
      ColorFunction ->  ( Hue[Rescale[f[#1, #2, #3 ], {0, 1}]] &)]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I forgot about the post after finding a solution myself. Still nice to see a different solution!